# Log4j StringMatchFilter and denyAll filter properties configuration

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j

Can anyone please let me know filter properties for a package where 
I want to separate the logs in two different logs files. Below is the configuration which I am trying use but its not working. I want deny logs 
based string like 'UserMgmt-' and allow rest logs in log1 appender and allow only log2 appender allow 'UserMgmt-' and deny rest allow logs.

```
log4j.logger.com.abc=DEBUG, log1
log4j.logger.com.abc=DEBUG, log2


log4j.appender.log1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.log1.Append=true
log4j.appender.log1.File=C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/logs/G_loAFg/UM.log
log4j.appender.log1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.log1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-6p [%c] %m%n
log4j.appender.log1.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.log1.filter.1.StringToMatch=UserMgmt-  
log4j.appender.log1.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=false

log4j.appender.log2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.log2.Append=true
log4j.appender.log2.File=C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/logs/PM.log
log4j.appender.log2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.log2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-6p [%c] %m%n
log4j.appender.log2.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.log2.filter.1.StringToMatch=UserMgmt-  
log4j.appender.log2.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added deny all filter in 1st log1 after that it worked

```
log4j.appender.log1.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```

---

```
log4j.logger.com.abc=DEBUG, log1
log4j.logger.com.abc=DEBUG, log2


log4j.appender.log1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.log1.Append=true
log4j.appender.log1.File=C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/logs/G_loAFg/UM.log
log4j.appender.log1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.log1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-6p [%c] %m%n
log4j.appender.log1.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.log1.filter.1.StringToMatch=UserMgmt-  
log4j.appender.log1.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=false
log4j.appender.log1.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
log4j.appender.log2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.log2.Append=true
log4j.appender.log2.File=C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/logs/PM.log
log4j.appender.log2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.log2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-6p [%c] %m%n
log4j.appender.log2.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.log2.filter.1.StringToMatch=UserMgmt-  
log4j.appender.log2.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
```

Answer (score 0):

using org.apache.log4j_1.2.17.jar  I set the filter to deny what I didn't want and then allowed everything else.

`log4j.appender.NormalAppender.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter`
`log4j.appender.NormalAppender.filter.1.StringToMatch=User.Dashboard`
`log4j.appender.NormalAppender.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=false`
`log4j.appender.NormalAppender.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.AllowAllFilter`